# displaying different style notification message from single controller for insert, update or error

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I have a controller from where I have to show notification to the user on three different scenarios.

1. successful insertion of data
2. successful update of data
3. in case of error

For these different scenarios, I want to display three different types of notification style boxes. Please see the attached image. 
These three boxes have different `CSS` styles for icons and box styling.

This is what I've written so far in my controller class

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult AddorEdit([Bind(Include = "Id,PatternName")] Pattern pattern)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pattern.Id <= 0)
                {
                    // for INSERT OPERATION
                    TempData["UserMessage"] = new { CssClassName = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible", Title = "Success!", Message = "Operation Done." };
                    return RedirectToAction("Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    // for UPDATE OPERATION
                    TempData["UserMessage"] = new { CssClassName = "alert alert-info alert-dismissible", Title = "Success!", Message = "Successful Update" };
                    return RedirectToAction("Success");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["UserMessage"] = new { CssClassName = "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible", Title = "Success!", Message = "Error." };
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
        }
```

1. Is it possible to use single `TempData` for displaying these three different boxes or I have to make three different TempData for these three different cases.

When I am trying to use the above TempData variable, getting red underline in CssClassName, Title and Message.

```
// view page
@if (TempData["UserMessage"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert @TempData["UserMessage"].CssClassName">
        <strong>@TempData["UserMessage"].Title</strong> @TempData["UserMessage"].Message
    </div>
}
```

Css for the notification boxes

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h5><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h5>
        Danger ...
</div>
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h5><i class="icon fas fa-info"></i> Alert!</h5>
            Info alert preview. This alert is dismissable.
</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h5><i class="icon fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Alert!</h5>
            Warning alert preview. This alert is dismissable.
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h5><i class="icon fas fa-check"></i> Alert!</h5>
            Success alert preview. This alert is dismissable.
</div>
```

Also, I came to this website while doing research on this matter but don't know whether it is suitable in my case or not.
https://exceptionnotfound.net/mvc-in-practice-tempdata/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have basically two options:

1. Making a class/struct containing the data required, fill it and add it to your viewbag/tempdata. Then on your viewpage you could cast the object to your class.
2. Convert your anonymous object to a JSON string, then convert it back in your viewpage

The second option is probably the easiest way of doing it. Simply add `using System.Web.Helpers` to your controller and set your `TempData` like this:

```
TempData["UserMessage"] = Json.Encode(new { CssClassName = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible", Title = "Success!", Message = "Operation Done." });
```

On your viewpage you can then use the following:

```
@if (TempData["UserMessage"] != null)
{
    dynamic userMessage = Json.Decode(TempData["UserMessage"]);
    <div class="@userMessage.CssClassName">
        <strong>@userMessage.Title</strong> @userMessage.Message
    </div>
}
```

---

For the sake of completeness, here is how you would do the first option:

Create a struct/class:

```
public struct AlertMessage 
{
    public string CssClassName;
    public string Title;
    public string Message;
}
```

Then in your controller set your TempData like this:

```
TempData["UserMessage"] = new AlertMessage() { CssClassName = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible", Title = "Success!", Message = "Operation Done." };
```

Then in your viewpage you can cast your TempData object back to your AlertMessage like this:

```
@if (TempData["UserMessage"] != null)
{
    AlertMessage userMessage = (TempData["UserMessage"] as AlertMessage);
    <div class="@userMessage.CssClassName">
        <strong>@userMessage.Title</strong> @userMessage.Message
    </div>
}
```

Please note that if you do this you have to add a `@using` at the top of your viewpage with the namespace of your struct/class.

Comment: Using firt option, `TempData["UserMessage"] = Json.Encode(new { CssClassName =...` 
getting error in controller `'Controller.Json(object)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context` showing red underline in `Json`. I have added also `using System.Web.Helpers;` Thank you!!!

Comment: Please look into the issue. I am unable solve the problem, still. Thank You!!!